# Table View: setEditing programmatically

Tags: objective-c

`NSMutableArray *objects` holds some objects which I use to display the content of my table view cells. If `objects.count` is 0 I would like to enable the editing mode of my table view when `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // If there is no content to present enable editing mode
    if (self.objects.count == 0) [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

This toggles the `self.editButtonItem` and inserts a new row (stating "Tap here to add a new element") into my table view:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (self.editing) {
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.objects count] inSection:0]] 
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }

    else {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.objects count] inSection:0]] 
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this setup results in a crash:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1914.85/UITableView.m:833
```

Is it not possible to toggle the editing mode programmatically? If the user touches the `self.editButtonItem` everything works fine – and as far as I know, this editButton does the same I'm doing in `viewDidLoad`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there are 2 different questions here.

one, it is possible to perform `setEditing:animated:` programmatically.

but i don't think that's what you really want to try to do here.  the editing mode is for the user to manually edit the table, and present the little red button on the left, and possibly the little movement indicator on the right if you have those settings set.

the better thing to do is when you find your objects has changed, perform a `[self.tableView reloadData];`, and just make sure that your `UITableViewDataSource` protocol methods implemented do the right thing.  this will include the implementation of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` (and possibly also `numberOfSections`) and also `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` .  this will cause the items to appear in the tableView as `objects` changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think there is a misunderstanding: I do want my tableview to present the little red button next to my "Tap here to add a new element" row. So it should look like the app has tapped the "Edit" button for the user. Before tapping the "Edit" button the view is empty as the tableview has no data to present. So the user will tap the "Edit" button in any case. And to save this step I would like to enable the editing mode programmatically.

Comment: if that is how you want to implement it, then still do all the stuff i recommended for causing the tableView to appear with changes to objects, and do so with setEditing:animated: implemented only with the calls to super and self.tableView, and don't perform the insert and delete within the setEditing:animated: call.  realize that for anything that the user deletes, you'll also have to implement tableView:commitEditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: .  same will be true if you have implemented a way to add an item while they are editing.

Comment: Your note not to perform insert and delete within `setEditing:animated:` actually helped me to solve this issue: I'm now using the proper way to handle this using my implementations of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` etc. In `setEditing:animated:` I'm reloading the content of my table view – just as recommended by you in your original answer. Thanks again!